# TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'pool_size' sent to create_engine() when using flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using 
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9 and
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
in my Flask application and want to connect to a sqlite db.

I get the error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'pool_size' sent to create_engine(), using configuration SQLiteDialect_pysqlite/NullPool/Engine.
```

because flask_sqlalchemy always tries to create the engine with the pool_size parameter.

As far as I understand the parameter pool_size is not allowed as an argument for the DefaultEngineStrategy in SQLAlchemy.

Does anyone know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this for either Python 2.7 or Python 3.5 on my machine using the exact library versions you specified and the MCVE on the Flask SQLAlchemy site. It must be something about how you have it set up, but you haven't shown any of that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found it: A colleague introduced the config param SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE in the Config Base Class to use it with mySQL.

Nevertheless it would be great if either flask_sqlalchemy or sqlalchemy would ignore the parameter instead of throwing an error.

I've created a ticket for the flask_sqlalchemy project:
https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/426

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this in my Flask/SQLALchemy/SQLite unit tests by adding two Flask configuration parameters:

```
app.config.update({
    'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE': None,
    'SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT': None
})
```